# Get with Reflection fields that are not generated by the compiler

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Recently I was writing a method to construct a graph with the dependencies between classes using Reflection and found the following problem. My method analyzes the return type of property, generic arguments of class definition and instance fields of those classes.

For inspection of instance fields of class I use the following method.

```
public static IEnumerable<FieldInfo> GetFields(Type classType)
{
    return classType
        .GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
}
```

To test it, I write the following class definition:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (var fieldInfo in GetFields(typeof(A)))
        Console.WriteLine(fieldInfo.Name);

    Console.ReadKey();
}

class A
{
    private ulong? _field1;

    public byte PropertyA { get; set; }

    public int PropertyB { get; set; }

    public bool PropertyC { get; set; }
}
```

I was in shock for a few seconds, to see the result. It was when I remembered that  .NET generates an instance field, Set and Get methods to emulate the properties.

[image]

When I inspected with [.NET Reflector](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/95789cdb-08f9-4dae-9b2f-fc45a452ad77?SRC=VSIDE) the library to see the code generated by the compiler, I find the following definition.

```
class A
{
    private ulong? _field1; 

    [CompilerGenerated]
    private Byte <PropertyA>k__BackingField;

    [CompilerGenerated]
    private Int32 <PropertyB>k__BackingField;

    [CompilerGenerated]
    private bool <PropertyC>k__BackingField;
}
```

So I modified the method to exclude the fields with CompilerGenerated attribute and his name match with some property.

```
public static IEnumerable<FieldInfo> GetFields(Type classType)
{
    var regex = new Regex(@"^<(?<PropertyName>\w+)>\w+$");

    var fieldInfoes = classType
            .GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

    foreach (var fieldInfo in fieldInfoes)
    {
        if (fieldInfo.GetCustomAttribute<CompilerGeneratedAttribute>() == null)
            yield return fieldInfo;
        else
        {
            var match = regex.Match(fieldInfo.Name);
            if (!match.Success) 
                continue;

            var propertyName = match.Groups[@"PropertyName"].Value;
            if (classType.GetProperty(propertyName) == null)
                yield return fieldInfo;
        }
    }
}
```

**QUESTIONS**

- There is some combination of BindingFlags I'm missing for these fields?
- There is another way of getting these fields because this code appears to me that is like killing a mosquito with a bazooka?

You can download the complete code [here](https://gist.github.com/josephrodriguez/0e6da9ff2e0896fe15ce).

Comment: You already did the right thing, great work man, nice to know about the GetCustomAttribute method.  Why did you need the fields if you only needed to check the property's value type?

Comment: Your method looks fine to me. I would probably just exclude all `[CompilerGenerated]` fields, unless there are some you know you want.

Comment: @Alexei my method return FieldInfo instances, not properties.

Answer (score 3):

You need the fields that are: `!field.IsDefined(typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute), false)`

```
public static IEnumerable<FieldInfo> GetFields(Type classType)
        {
            var allFields = classType
                .GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

            var definedFields = from field in allFields
                                where !field.IsDefined(typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute), false)
                                select field;

            return definedFields;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks @Rami, but IsDefined method here meets the same objective as GetCustomAttribute method. Also I check for the existence of property from the match of field name.

Comment: @Joseph I think that this is the minimal code that let you get the fields that actually defined by you and not generated by compiler. What you show in your example is doing the job as well, but it is overhead.