# GetFields doesn't ignore events

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Can anyone tell me why are public events detected by the customType.GetFields( BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance )?
I even created custom empty attributes that are supposed to work as flags for what fields to include and it still doesn't work. When i do the GetCustomAttribute() it says null, even though i put the attribute there

```cs
var Fields = customType.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).
Where(field => field.GetCustomAttribute( typeof(PrivateIgnore) ) == null ).ToArray();
```

This is the custom class

```cs
public class Health : Property
{
    int _maxMealth;
    [PrivateIgnore] int _healthAmount;
    [PrivateIgnore] public event Action<GameEntity> TakesDamage;//i added the attribute just in case (even though it shouldn't be detected because it's public)
    [PrivateIgnore] public event Action<GameEntity> Dies;
    public int HealthAmount => _healthAmount;//this isn't detected
//when i tested, public int fields are not detected as well
}
```

And this is my custom Attribute

```cs
public class PrivateIgnore : Attribute {}
```

Comment: You mean it is picking up the generated fields? https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFDKgZgASwwCQKYCGANgC4AWGA9JSBgAoBOA9gA54MkCeyA3shgIwBLAHYkMAfQC2BAB4BZQqTIBufoIDajIQDcCJPAEkA5iKYM8AXWFjJZJeQCCUpgFcxapIIxaGu/Uam5lZYmHg6eLZQcDAAPNEADAB8GAAqBADWeADOACIEMsZ4KtRCGATAwHjAGOR45SQkfgBGrgYYAFau2eKiGADGBNn1ABThkbVkbsYUQuLZU65EwCIA5OLN9VUG/QY1m4Pd9XOr2aEAlOoCvv4GJmYW1ugY41Ex8XDJGLlCOZ7ez1E4nwxCcLnc4gAvCkJPZQWRnG4PNRyEIzmi1uJtnhdtVkNQAO72ETCWo5PYAGlCNnEADNfsszgQLBgzFi8Ds9uUzgS8EQiMgAL7IVCYbDaPR3IIs2iORotNr1HiCoA

Comment: If so https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31528140/get-with-reflection-fields-that-are-not-generated-by-the-compiler

Comment: @RandRandom Oh, it works fine now. So the problem was that GetFields picked up compile generated fields? Is it fine if i just add a condition like `field.GetCustomAttribute<CompilerGeneratedAttribute>() != null`?

Comment: Yes, that should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event is separated into different fields that all have [CompileGenerated] attribute on them. So to ignore events and other data types you have to include a check for that attribute:

```cs
if(field.GetCustomAttribute<CompilerGeneratedAttribute>() != null) return;
```